# Is it possible to provide a custom key for SQL HashBytes function?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, hmacsha1

I'm using HMACSHA1 with machine validation key in C# .NET 4.0 to generate hash in my application but I can't seem to find any resource on TSQL HashBytes function being able to take a key string.

Can anyone provide a working example to generate matching hashes with the same key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, SQL server does not have a documented function for HMACSHA1. You will likely have to write a [SQL-CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR) function to do that. Given that you already have the code in C#, it should be fairly simple to convert that into a SQL-CLR scalar function. You *may* be able to do something incredibly hack-ish by re-implementing the algorithm in T-SQL; but it would be inefficient and prone to error. T-SQL wasn't meant for that.